Problem with a PL/SQL BLOCK error: NO_DATA_FOUND
I keep getting the NO_DATA_FOUND error, I don't know why when I use FOR it doesn't give me results, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
--EJERCICIO N2

DECLARE
    
    v_tramo1_min NUMBER := 1000001;
    v_tramo1_max NUMBER := 3000000;
    v_tramo2_min NUMBER := 3000001;
    v_tramo2_max NUMBER := 6000000;
    v_tramo3 NUMBER := 6000000;
    
    --VARRAY VALOR PESOS NORMALES
    TYPE tipo_varray_pesos IS VARRAY(3)
        OF NUMBER;
    
    --INCIALIZAMOS VARRAY
    varray_pesos_extras tipo_varray_pesos;
    --DATOS DEL VARRAY
    v_peso_extra1 NUMBER := 300;
    v_peso_extra2 NUMBER := 550;
    v_peso_extra3 NUMBER := 700;
    
    --ID MINIMO Y MAXIMO CLIENTE
    v_id_min NUMBER;
    v_id_max NUMBER;
    
    ----------------------------------
    v_nro_cliente NUMBER;
    v_run_cliente NUMBER;
    v_nombre_cliente VARCHAR2(50);
    v_tipo_cliente VARCHAR2(50);
    v_monto_solic_creditos NUMBER;
    ----------------------------------
    
    TYPE tipo_registro_todosuma IS RECORD(
        nro_cliente NUMBER,
        run_cliente VARCHAR2(15),
        nombre_cliente VARCHAR2(50));
        
    v_registro_todosuma tipo_registro_todosuma;
    v_codigo_cliente NUMBER;
 
BEGIN

    --SE DEBE TRUNCAR LA TABLA CLIENTE_TODOSUMA EN TIEMPO DE EJECUCION
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('TRUNCATE TABLE CLIENTE_TODOSUMA');
    
    --EL VALOR DE LOS PESOS NORMALES $1200 Y LOS PESOS EXTRAS($100, $300, $550 Y $700) DEBERAN SER INGRESADOS A UN VARRAY
    varray_pesos_extras := tipo_varray_pesos(v_peso_extra1, v_peso_extra2, v_peso_extra3);

    --SE DEBEN PROCESAR TODOS LOS CLIENTES DE UNA SOLA VEZ
    SELECT 
        MIN(nro_cliente),
        MAX(nro_cliente)
    INTO
        v_id_min,
        v_id_max
    FROM CLIENTE;
    
    FOR codigo_cliente IN v_id_min .. v_id_max LOOP 
        SELECT
            c.nro_cliente,
            c.numrun,
            c.pnombre ||' '|| c.snombre ||' '|| c.appaterno ||' '|| c.apmaterno,
            tc.nombre_tipo_cliente,
            SUM(cc.monto_solicitado)
        INTO
            v_nro_cliente,
            v_run_cliente,
            v_nombre_cliente,
            v_tipo_cliente,
            v_monto_solic_creditos
        FROM CLIENTE c JOIN TIPO_CLIENTE tc ON(c.cod_tipo_cliente = tc.cod_tipo_cliente)
        JOIN CREDITO_CLIENTE cc ON(c.nro_cliente = cc.nro_cliente)
        WHERE c.nro_cliente = codigo_cliente
        GROUP BY
            c.nro_cliente,
            c.numrun,
            c.pnombre ||' '|| c.snombre ||' '|| c.appaterno ||' '|| c.apmaterno,
            tc.nombre_tipo_cliente;

        --SE DEBE GENERAR LA INFORMACION DEL AÑO ANTERIOR
    END LOOP;
--LOS CALCULOS SE DEBEN REALIZAR EN SENTENCIAS PL/SQL

--EL RESULTADO DEL PROCESO DEBE QUEDAR ALMACENADO EN LA TABLA CLIENTE_TODOSUMA
END;

This error keeps appearing to me, I want to obtain data from three different tables with a for in order to obtain the data of each client, not all the ids of the CLIENTE table are in CREDITO_CLIENTE. I do the query without a block and it gives me results, I think the problem is in the comparison of id's.

Depending on what you want, you may be able to do it in a single SQL query (without using PL/SQL) using a row-generator to generate all the nro_cliente values and then OUTER JOINing to the desired tables (which will also handle the NO_DATA_FOUND exception). Then you do not need to keep context-switching between PL/SQL and SQL and can read everything in a single query:
SELECT a.nro_cliente,
       c.numrun,
       c.pnombre ||' '|| c.snombre ||' '|| c.appaterno ||' '|| c.apmaterno,
       tc.nombre_tipo_cliente,
       cc.monto_solic_creditos
FROM   (
         SELECT min_nro_cliente + LEVEL - 1 AS nro_cliente
         FROM   (
           SELECT MIN(nro_cliente) AS min_nro_cliente,
                  MAX(nro_cliente) AS max_nro_cliente
           FROM   cliente
         )
         CONNECT BY min_nro_cliente + LEVEL - 1 <= max_nro_cliente
       ) a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          cliente c
          INNER JOIN TIPO_CLIENTE tc
          ON (c.cod_tipo_cliente = tc.cod_tipo_cliente)
          INNER JOIN (
            SELECT nro_cliente,
                   SUM(monto_solicitado) AS monto_solic_creditos
            FROM   CREDITO_CLIENTE
            GROUP BY nro_cliente
          ) cc
          ON (c.nro_cliente = cc.nro_cliente)
       )
       ON (a.nro_cliente = c.nro_cliente)

If you did want to use PL/SQL then wrap the query in a FOR loop:
DECLARE
  v_tramo1_min NUMBER := 1000001;
  v_tramo1_max NUMBER := 3000000;
  v_tramo2_min NUMBER := 3000001;
  v_tramo2_max NUMBER := 6000000;
  v_tramo3     NUMBER := 6000000;
    
  --VARRAY VALOR PESOS NORMALES
  TYPE tipo_varray_pesos IS VARRAY(3) OF NUMBER;
    
  --DATOS DEL VARRAY
  v_peso_extra1 NUMBER := 300;
  v_peso_extra2 NUMBER := 550;
  v_peso_extra3 NUMBER := 700;

  --INCIALIZAMOS VARRAY
  varray_pesos_extras tipo_varray_pesos := tipo_varray_pesos(v_peso_extra1, v_peso_extra2, v_peso_extra3);

  TYPE tipo_registro_todosuma IS RECORD(
        nro_cliente NUMBER,
        run_cliente VARCHAR2(15),
        nombre_cliente VARCHAR2(50));
        
  v_registro_todosuma tipo_registro_todosuma;
  v_codigo_cliente NUMBER;
 
BEGIN
  --SE DEBE TRUNCAR LA TABLA CLIENTE_TODOSUMA EN TIEMPO DE EJECUCION
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('TRUNCATE TABLE CLIENTE_TODOSUMA');
    
  FOR c IN (
    SELECT a.nro_cliente,
           c.numrun,
           c.pnombre ||' '|| c.snombre ||' '|| c.appaterno ||' '|| c.apmaterno
             AS nombre_cliente,
           tc.nombre_tipo_cliente,
           cc.monto_solic_creditos
    FROM   (
             SELECT min_nro_cliente + LEVEL - 1 AS nro_cliente
             FROM   (
               SELECT MIN(nro_cliente) AS min_nro_cliente,
                      MAX(nro_cliente) AS max_nro_cliente
               FROM   cliente
             )
             CONNECT BY min_nro_cliente + LEVEL - 1 <= max_nro_cliente
           ) a
           LEFT OUTER JOIN (
              cliente c
              INNER JOIN TIPO_CLIENTE tc
              ON (c.cod_tipo_cliente = tc.cod_tipo_cliente)
              INNER JOIN (
                SELECT nro_cliente,
                       SUM(monto_solicitado) AS monto_solic_creditos
                FROM   CREDITO_CLIENTE
                GROUP BY nro_cliente
              ) cc
              ON (c.nro_cliente = cc.nro_cliente)
           )
           ON (a.nro_cliente = c.nro_cliente)
  ) LOOP
    -- Do stuff with c.nro_cleinte, c.numrun, etc.
    NULL;
  END LOOP;
  --LOS CALCULOS SE DEBEN REALIZAR EN SENTENCIAS PL/SQL

  --EL RESULTADO DEL PROCESO DEBE QUEDAR ALMACENADO EN LA TABLA CLIENTE_TODOSUMA
END;
/


It depends on what you want to do in case nothing is returned by that select statement, but - generally speaking - you should handle it. One option is to use an inner BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END block like in this example. In exception handling section, I'm simply skipping over it, but you can do whatever you want.
BEGIN
   --SE DEBE TRUNCAR LA TABLA CLIENTE_TODOSUMA EN TIEMPO DE EJECUCION
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('TRUNCATE TABLE CLIENTE_TODOSUMA');

   --EL VALOR DE LOS PESOS NORMALES $1200 Y LOS PESOS EXTRAS($100, $300, $550 Y $700) DEBERAN SER INGRESADOS A UN VARRAY
   varray_pesos_extras := tipo_varray_pesos (v_peso_extra1, v_peso_extra2, v_peso_extra3);

   --SE DEBEN PROCESAR TODOS LOS CLIENTES DE UNA SOLA VEZ
   SELECT MIN (nro_cliente), MAX (nro_cliente)
     INTO v_id_min, v_id_max
     FROM CLIENTE;

   FOR codigo_cliente IN v_id_min .. v_id_max
   LOOP
--> inner block begins here 
      BEGIN
           -- this query raised NO_DATA_FOUND
           SELECT c.nro_cliente,
                  c.numrun,
                  c.pnombre || ' ' || c.snombre || ' ' || c.appaterno || ' ' || c.apmaterno,
                  tc.nombre_tipo_cliente,
                  SUM (cc.monto_solicitado)
             INTO v_nro_cliente,
                  v_run_cliente,
                  v_nombre_cliente,
                  v_tipo_cliente,
                  v_monto_solic_creditos
             FROM CLIENTE c
                  JOIN TIPO_CLIENTE tc ON (c.cod_tipo_cliente = tc.cod_tipo_cliente)
                  JOIN CREDITO_CLIENTE cc ON (c.nro_cliente = cc.nro_cliente)
            WHERE c.nro_cliente = codigo_cliente
         GROUP BY c.nro_cliente,
                  c.numrun,
                     c.pnombre
                  || ' '
                  || c.snombre
                  || ' '
                  || c.appaterno
                  || ' '
                  || c.apmaterno,
                  tc.nombre_tipo_cliente;
      --SE DEBE GENERAR LA INFORMACION DEL AÑO ANTERIOR
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
         THEN
            -- don't do anything (or handle it, somehow)
            NULL;
      END;
--> inner block ends here

   END LOOP;
--LOS CALCULOS SE DEBEN REALIZAR EN SENTENCIAS PL/SQL

--EL RESULTADO DEL PROCESO DEBE QUEDAR ALMACENADO EN LA TABLA CLIENTE_TODOSUMA
END;

